# Discard saved release from "Publishing overview" on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I accidentally created release with full rollout, then I re-uploaded it with desired 50% rollout

When I go to Publishing Overview, there is a button that says "Send 2 changes for review".
I do not want to send the full rollout for review, but I can't figure out how to delete it, or how to only send the test build.

[image]